# Compile Nginx on Intel Atom

Tags: nginx, cpu, intel-atom

Are there any special options to compile nginx for Intel Atom CPU ? I saw an option called --with-cpu-opt the possible values are : pentium, pentiumpro, pentium3, pentium4, athlon, opteron, sparc32, sparc64, ppc64, but I don't see Intel Atom here